# Transform php array to json (coinbase)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I’m searching for a solution to read data from an PHP array in a class property.

Request:

```
$accounts = $client->getAccounts();
```

Here’s the resulting array:

```
Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection Object
(
    [previousUri:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection:private] => 
    [nextUri:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection:private] => 
    [resources:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account Object
                (
                    [name:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => BTC Wallet
                    [primary:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => 1
                    [type:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => wallet
                    [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => BTC
                    [balance:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => 0.00001
                            [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => BTC
                        )

                    [nativeBalance:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object
                        (
                            [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => 0.01
                            [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => CHF
                        )

                    [createdAt:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-11-04 01:35:13.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )

                    [updatedAt:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account:private] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-11-04 14:24:11.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 2
                            [timezone] => Z
                        )

                    [id:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
                    [resource:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => account
                    [resourcePath:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => /v2/accounts/XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
                    [rawData:Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Resource:private] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
                            [name] => BTC Wallet
                            [primary] => 1
                            [type] => wallet
                            [currency] => BTC
                            [balance] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => 0.001
                                    [currency] => BTC
                                )

                            [created_at] => 2017-11-04T01:35:13Z
                            [updated_at] => 2017-11-04T14:24:11Z
                            [resource] => account
                            [resource_path] => /v2/accounts/XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
                            [native_balance] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => 0.01
                                    [currency] => CHF
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to read the `$accounts['rawData']['id']` with the value XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
I have try to transform these responses to a JSON array like this:

```
$aaax = json_encode($accounts);
$bbbx = json_decode($aaax, true);
```

but it doesn’t work. On

```
print_r($bbbx)
```

I receive only an

```
Array
(
)
```

Do you know how I can read/take data from the output array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your class’s properties all have `private` [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). This means that your code outside the class can’t read or modify those properties.

You need to modify your class to make the properties accessible by your code, or at least tell PHP to include the private properties when you run `json_encode()`. Assuming you can’t do that because this is a library, not code you wrote, you need to wrap the class in a wrapper class that implements [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ed Cottrell for your help and also for the corrections of the technical terms. That's the best way for me to learn. I have try to solve this problem with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize. No way (for me...)

Now i have found another solution to access to the data. I use the php wrapper:
https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

There is a method to access on RawData

```
$data = $client->decodeLastResponse();
```

On my case the following code:

```
$accounts = $client->getAccounts();
$dataX = $client->decodeLastResponse();
print_r($dataX);
```

So I obtain the following response:

```
Array
(
    [pagination] => Array
        (
            [ending_before] => 
            [starting_after] => 
            [limit] => 25
            [order] => desc
            [previous_uri] => 
            [next_uri] => 
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [name] => BTC Wallet
                    [primary] => 1
                    [type] => wallet
                    [currency] => BTC
                    [balance] => Array
                        (
                            [amount] => 0.001
                            [currency] => BTC
                        )

                    [created_at] => 2017-11-04T01:35:13Z
                    [updated_at] => 2017-11-04T14:24:11Z
                    [resource] => account
                    [resource_path] => /v2/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                    [native_balance] => Array
                        (
                            [amount] => 0.001
                            [currency] => CHF
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

So it is perfectly accessible
Thank you again (for opening my mind..:-)) I found this solution with google search "coinbase jsonserialize"... this was your input..